# Properly release target Surface used for Camera2 repeating request

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

Let say I have `CameraCaptureSession session1` and `Surface s1` as a target for repeating `CaptureRequest`. Now I want to change the output size. To this end I can create another `Surface s2` with the appropriate size and create another `CameraCaptureSession session2`.
Now I will use `s2` as a target for future `CaptureRequests` so I don't need `s1` anymore.  Moreover, I want to create `s2` only after `s1` is released so I can save resources.

When exactly `s1` may be released? May I release `s1` right after `session1.close()`, or should I wait until the `onClosed(Session)` is triggered and release `s1` only after that?

---

The second approach sounds correct to me but I am confused a little bit by the [optimization](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/impl/CameraDeviceImpl.java) `replaceSessionClose()` I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to wait for onClosed, though at worst case you'd miss one or two frames being sent to the old session, and there'd be some amount of error logging in logcat, if you release the surface early.

But it won't cause the new session to fail to be created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Did I understand correctly: the highest price I pay for early release is the missed frames and logcat messages, so if I am not interested in these frames it is totally safe to release surfaces right after `Session.close()` and no runtime errors will occur?

Comment: If you've wired up the CaptureCallback#onCaptureFailed method (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback) for the last requests in the session with a released Surface, you may get some instances of that being invoked as the requests can't be processed with nowhere to send buffers to, but no other errors should occur.